# Create dynamic select boxes in php

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, select

I have 2 select options, Make and Model.. I have data in my DB with a bunch of different vehicles and would like the model field to update based on the make selection..

** UPDATED QUESTION WITH EXTERNAL PHP FILE FOR AJAX CALL **

So I made this change, I have dataAJax.php -

```
if(isset($_POST["make"]) && !empty($_POST["make"])){
$query = $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT Make, Model FROM inv WHERE Make = ".$_POST['Make']."");
$rowCount = $query->num_rows;
if($rowCount > 0){
    echo '<option value="">Select model</option>';
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
        echo '<option value="'.$row['Model'].'">'.$row['Model'].'</option>';
    }
}else{
    echo '<option value="">Model not available</option>';
}
}
```

Index.php -

```
$query = $conn->query("SELECT DISTINCT Make FROM inv");
$rowCount = $query->num_rows;
?>
<select name="make" id="make">
<option value="">Select Make</option>
<?php
if($rowCount > 0){
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
        echo '<option value="'.$row['Make'].'">'.$row['Make'].'</option>';
    }
}
?>
</select>

<select name="model" id="model">
    <option value="">Select Make first</option>
</select>
```

And here is my ajax call -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#make').on('change',function(){
    var make = $(this).val();
    if(make){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'dataAjax.php',
            data:'make='+make,
            success:function(html){
                $('#model').html(html);
            }
        }); 
    }else{
        $('#make').html('<option value="">Select Model First</option>');
    }
});
});
```

The problem I have is it doesn't populate the model field it just gets the else statement " Model Not Available"

Comment: Well, there's an ajax way and a more basic jquery way (hiding and showing the second <select> based off of the first).

Besides that, you haven't really done much. 
The general idea is that we fix code (not write it)

Comment: You have to create a separate PHP file which will process the query for the car model based on the car make selection. An ajax request to this second PHP file will update the second select in your main page. There is no ajax code attempts here above. Seach SO about ajax, then try something.

Comment: Ok thanks, I updated the question with my problem, it is not pulling the data using the post data

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem it was with my sql query in dataAjax.php -

```
$make = $_POST['make'];

$query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM inv WHERE Make = '$make'");
$rowCount = $query->num_rows;
if($rowCount > 0){
    echo '<option value="">Select model</option>';
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
        echo '<option value="'.$row['Model'].'">'.$row['Model'].'</option>';
    }
}else{
    echo '<option value="">Model not available</option>';
}
```